# Using Capistrano for local development tasks

Tags: capistrano, development-environment, ezpublish

I'm currently in the process of setting up a development environment around the [eZPublish](http://ez.no) CMS.

I would like to use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for deployments. What I'm curious about would be to also use Capistrano for local development tasks.

These tasks would be doing stuff like:

- Creating a new site using eZPublish. This would create a git repo for the site, set up a databse, create Solr core etc.
- Pulling down an already existing site. Basically clone an existing git repo to a specific directory, and making sure all dependencies are in place.

I'm unsure if Capistrano is the right tool for these tasks. As it would mostly just be a set of commands which would be ran locally.

Does anyone have any experience using Capistrano for this use case. Or would you recommend taking another route whit this?

Comment: Nifty, have you come to a solution? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Capistrano is a deployment tool. What you're really looking for are tools to make local development easier: set up server & packages, clone your repo, pull down content.

Capistrano might be one part of this solution to the extent that you might specify a local deployment command.

But what you're really looking for are provisioning, configuration and virtualization solutions. I'd suggest a combination of [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) and either [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, as a proof of concept, I have developed a bunch of Capistrano recipes to work with eZ Publish. Obviously it's oriented for deployment but it also has cool local features such as :

- retrieving the production database in order to import it on your local instance
- same for your var/ directory

This scripts are under development and not yet very stable (it will be the case for 0.3.0 which will be release in a couple of days), so feedback is muchly appreciated.

Readmore at http://alafon.github.com/alcapon/

Comment: thanks foobar, looks interesting.
Is Alcapon still a proof of concept & "not very stable"?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Can't say that it's a proof of concept anymore, since I use it for many of my customers. It might need a bit of polish but it's quite stable and should be usable on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano's superpower is distributing and coordinating commands via SSH.

Rake is the right tool for the job for tasks you can run on your local machine.